# Word for website menu button for "miscellaneous" items

Tags: word-choice

Context: I'm proofing a translation for a website that includes layered menu buttons. The site has many of the typical main menu buttons you see on commercial websites: About Us, Products, and so on. The original text has 
"Etc." for one menu button, with the layer under it including "Site Map," "Privacy Policy," "Legal Notices," "Terms and Conditions," and "Affiliates."

"Etc." doesn't really seem suitable here, as it gives no real indication of what is contained under that menu. I looked around online at various websites and did some Google image searches, but couldn't find any similar/relevant name for such menu items. It seems most of the items under this menu tend to show up at the bottom of the page on most websites (particularly "Site Map" and "Privacy Policy"); alas, as it's a translation, I don't get to make the call on how this information is presented, so it stays jammed under a menu button.

I assume it will look something like this on the site:

> About Us | Products | PR Center | Customer Service | ???

Since I'm tagging this under word choice, I'm obliged to offer a selection of words. Here are the ones I've come up with:

- Miscellaneous
- Etc.
- Other
- More
- Additional Information
- References
- Resources
- Other Resources
- Additional Resources

but I welcome any suitable alternatives I'm not thinking of.

Comment: (To the editors out there, re-tag if you feel this comes across as more of a single-word-request question than a word-choice question.)

Comment: I don't have any problem with *Etc.* but maybe "*Site Info*" could work.

Comment: I'd use **"More"**

Comment: @Jim Thank you. That does seem to cover most, if not all, the items they're wanting to put under this menu.

Comment: I think you'd be better asking the question in UX https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think most sites avoid this completely. If some of the pages don't fit into any group with a useful name, they just leave them out of the navigation bar completely. They may provide a "Site Map" page that has links to everything.

Comment: How about *miscellany*?

Comment: @Barmar In my question above: "It seems most of the items under this menu tend to show up at the bottom of the page on most websites (particularly "Site Map" and "Privacy Policy"); alas, as it's a translation, I don't get to make the call on how this information is presented, so it stays jammed under a menu button."